# List all stereotypes in code template

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there any way to list all class stereotypes in an Enterprise Architect code template? `%classStereotype%` only gives me the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. [Sparx help](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/software_engineering/class_field_substitution_macro.html) lists nothing useful. What you "could" do is to write an add-in and call it via EXEC_ADDIN as described in [this part of EA's help](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/extending_uml_models/functionmacros.html).

Comment: Thanks. Seems that you're right. I asked the same question in Sparx' forum and an add-in seems to be solution right now. EA 13 might support querying for specific stereotypes, but upgrading to a beta version isn't an option for me, so I didn't check that.